# ggplot2: Adjust legend symbols in overlayed plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to create a plot, in which a histogram gets overlayed by a density. Here is my result so far using some example data:

[image]

```
library("ggplot2")

set.seed(1234)
a <- round(rnorm(10000, 5, 5), 0)
b <- rnorm(10000, 5, 7)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = a, y = ..density.., col = "histogram", linetype = "histogram"), fill = "blue") +
  stat_density(aes(x = b, y = ..density.., col = "density", linetype = "density"), geom = "line") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "white"), 
                 breaks = c("density", "histogram")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "solid")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = c(.75, .75), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
```

Unfortunately I can not figure out how I can change the symbols in the legend properly. **The first symbol should be a relatively thick red line and the second symbol should be a blue box without the white line in the middle.**

Based on some internet research, I tried to change different things in `scale_linetype_manual` and further I tried to use `override.aes`, but I could not figure out how I would have to use it in this specific case.

---

**EDIT -** Here is the best solution based on the very helpful answers below.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = a, y = ..density.., linetype = "histogram"), 
                 fill = "blue",
# I added the following 2 lines to keep the white colour arround the histogram.
                 col = "white") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "solid")) +
  stat_density(aes(x = b, y = ..density.., linetype = "density"), 
               geom = "line", color = "red") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = c(.75, .75), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.key = element_blank()) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1, 0), 
                                                     fill = c("white", "blue"), 
                                                     size = c(1.5, 1.5))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you thought, most of the work can be done via `override.aes` for `linetype`.

Note I removed `color` from the `aes` of both layers to avoid some trouble I was having with the legend box outline.  Doing this also avoids the need for the `scale_*_*` function calls.  To set the color of the density line I used `color` outside of `aes`.

In `override.aes` I set the `linetype` to be solid or blank, the `fill` to be either white or blue, and the `size` to be 2 or 0 for the density box and histogram box, respectively.

```
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(x = a, y = ..density.., linetype = "histogram"), fill = "blue") +
    stat_density(aes(x = b, y = ..density.., linetype = "density"), geom = "line", color = "red") +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
          legend.position = c(.75, .75), 
          legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
          legend.key = element_blank()) +
    guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1, 0), 
                                                       fill = c("white", "blue"), 
                                                       size = c(2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the perfect solution! I added 2 lines to your code, because I want to keep the white colour arround the histogram (see edited post above).

Answer (score 2):

[image]The `fill` and `colour` aesthetics are labelled by `histogram` and `density` respectively, and their values set using `scale_*_manual`.  Doing so maps directly to the desired legend without needing any overrides.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = a, y = ..density.., fill = "histogram")) +
  stat_density(aes(x = b, y = ..density.., colour="density"), geom = "line") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red")) +
  labs(fill="", colour="") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = c(.75, .75), 
        legend.box.just = "left",
        legend.background = element_rect(fill=NULL),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill=NULL),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer, although I took the soloution of aosmith, because I prefer a common legend for both symbols.